# Find a XML content

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to get data from a file through nokogiri like this:

```
From: XXX <xxx@xxx.com> 
To: yyy@yyy.com 
Subject: Sabertooth; zebra oto Hammerjaw pompano, cusk-eel lighthousefish frogmouth catfish. 

----- BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE ----- 
Hash: SHA1 

Dear yyy@yyy.com: 

Sabertooth; zebra oto Hammerjaw pompano, cusk-eel lighthousefish frogmouth catfish. "Smalleye squaretail antenna codlet dartfish peacock flounder plaice, luminous hake oceanic flyingfish tiger shark, bramble shark, California halibut. Australian prowfish lake chub knifefish African lungfish; southern Dolly Varden pike conger. Gouramie glass catfish loosejaw, three-toothed puffer. Nase ridgehead featherfin knifefish Rattail gulper false brotula Atlantic eel zebra oto. Marlin mahi-mahi freshwater eel false brotula mojarra naked-back knifefish Steve fish bocaccio. Amago kanyu algae eater bullhead shark orangespine unicorn fish bangus, "Pacific cod zander banjo catfish half-gill pejerrey Indian mul." 
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<Case> 
   <ID> 48456856568 </ ID> 
   <Status> Open </ Status> 
   <Severity> Normal </ Severity> 
</ Case> 
<Complainant> 
   <Entity> Sabertooth </ Entity> 
   <Contact> California halibut </ Contact> 
   <Address> Pacific cod zander banjo catfish half-gill pejerrey Indian mul. </ Address> 
   <phone> +1 (352) 584 8413 </ Phone> 
   <Email> Xxx@xxx.com </ Email> 
</ Complainant> 
<Service_Provider> 
   <Entity> Hammerjaw pompano </ Entity> 
   <Contact/> 
   <Address/> 
   <Phone/> 
   <Email> Yyy@yyy.com </ Email> 
</ Service_Provider> 
<Source> 
   <TimeStamp> 2012-12-30T14: 24:05 Z </ TimeStamp> 
   <IP_Address> 158.01.52.23 </ IP_Address> 
   <Port> 8080 </ Port> 
   <Type> Browser </ Type> 
   <Protocol="IP"/> 
   <UserName/> 
   <Number_Files> 5 </ Number_Files> 
</ Source> 
<Content> 
   <Item> 
   <TimeStamp> 2012-12-30T14: 24:05 Z </ TimeStamp> 
    <Title> Dolly Varden pike conger </ Title> 
    <FileName> Dolly Varden pike conger </ FileName> 
    <FileSize> 2143534544 </ FileSize> 
    <InfoHash> 67asdv6a6sdv7d7sfb3c32da79dcc9a6cdc70 </ InfoHash> 
   </ Item> 
</ Content> 
<History/> 
<Notes/> 
<Type Retraction="false"/> 
<Verification/> 
</ Infringement> 

----- BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE ----- 
Version: GnuPG 

0zjdfbkHGBVJKhdbvskjdvbhBHSDJvhbvEtqs/WYMcIAL1 +4 ufOjdvXiDLcN1PzM/QJ 
IIj9KCq + / PYuMU6fTd800EOcbRX43RgeX6Qrgu + MDdDbte + CwKZL2Q28IZ0Viv +8 
YItYXdgwhNnUO2QE7jn/g5KXn4v72QqpnsPJjWQVVD12 + h6DDUdaQHMsTdYyYIVD 
Jkc8dPDVTLutVnuK2HZ4wQWRoiIWIMsUzePUht0eWi7DJFOlC5NuwS + E6FuxtgFj 
IwJyCr/dLC/u6YtVCAb37UUSu7k3F5iD3hFTt1RyswK7HBDizV1CHIlc2diARfkL
CwRpYc/SlpZNgbAXaUzwHhtIQjCuRXQGsXtvDFke4CvM9nGe6Uk095yVOAKla1Y = 
= mVny 
----- END PGP SIGNATURE -----
```

I need information such as the sender ip which is in / Source / IP_Address, email sender, who is in Address / Email, From Field is located in the beginning of the letter, the letter itself. How it can be implemented in Ruby using Nokogiri?

I'm trying to get data IP addresses as follows:

```
def ip_address 
ip = Nokogiri :: XML ("mail / *. txt") 
ip.each {| node | 
p node.inner_xml if node.name == "IP_Address" 
}
```

But I did not go out. Does anyone have ideas how I get the data from this type of file?

Comment: Did you take a bite an XML from the whole email before passing it to nokogiri?

Comment: @mudasobwa No, I thought nokogiri recognizes xml within the file

Comment: @mudasobwa What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokogiri won't parse the mail message, so you have to get rid of the non-XML content:

```
message = 'From: XXX <xxx@xxx.com> 
To: yyy@yyy.com 
Subject: Sabertooth; zebra oto Hammerjaw pompano, cusk-eel lighthousefish frogmouth catfish. 

----- BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE ----- 
Hash: SHA1 

Dear yyy@yyy.com: 

Sabertooth; zebra oto Hammerjaw pompano, cusk-eel lighthousefish frogmouth catfish. "Smalleye squaretail antenna codlet dartfish peacock flounder plaice, luminous hake oceanic flyingfish tiger shark, bramble shark, California halibut. Australian prowfish lake chub knifefish African lungfish; southern Dolly Varden pike conger. Gouramie glass catfish loosejaw, three-toothed puffer. Nase ridgehead featherfin knifefish Rattail gulper false brotula Atlantic eel zebra oto. Marlin mahi-mahi freshwater eel false brotula mojarra naked-back knifefish Steve fish bocaccio. Amago kanyu algae eater bullhead shark orangespine unicorn fish bangus, "Pacific cod zander banjo catfish half-gill pejerrey Indian mul." 
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<Case> 
   <ID> 48456856568 </ ID> 
   <Status> Open </ Status> 
   <Severity> Normal </ Severity> 
</ Case> 
<Complainant> 
   <Entity> Sabertooth </ Entity> 
   <Contact> California halibut </ Contact> 
   <Address> Pacific cod zander banjo catfish half-gill pejerrey Indian mul. </ Address> 
   <phone> +1 (352) 584 8413 </ Phone> 
   <Email> Xxx@xxx.com </ Email> 
</ Complainant> 
<Service_Provider> 
   <Entity> Hammerjaw pompano </ Entity> 
   <Contact/> 
   <Address/> 
   <Phone/> 
   <Email> Yyy@yyy.com </ Email> 
</ Service_Provider> 
<Source> 
   <TimeStamp> 2012-12-30T14: 24:05 Z </ TimeStamp> 
   <IP_Address> 158.01.52.23 </ IP_Address> 
   <Port> 8080 </ Port> 
   <Type> Browser </ Type> 
   <Protocol="IP"/> 
   <UserName/> 
   <Number_Files> 5 </ Number_Files> 
</ Source> 
<Content> 
   <Item> 
   <TimeStamp> 2012-12-30T14: 24:05 Z </ TimeStamp> 
    <Title> Dolly Varden pike conger </ Title> 
    <FileName> Dolly Varden pike conger </ FileName> 
    <FileSize> 2143534544 </ FileSize> 
    <InfoHash> 67asdv6a6sdv7d7sfb3c32da79dcc9a6cdc70 </ InfoHash> 
   </ Item> 
</ Content> 
<History/> 
<Notes/> 
<Type Retraction="false"/> 
<Verification/> 
</ Infringement> 

----- BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE ----- 
Version: GnuPG 

0zjdfbkHGBVJKhdbvskjdvbhBHSDJvhbvEtqs/WYMcIAL1 +4 ufOjdvXiDLcN1PzM/QJ 
IIj9KCq + / PYuMU6fTd800EOcbRX43RgeX6Qrgu + MDdDbte + CwKZL2Q28IZ0Viv +8 
YItYXdgwhNnUO2QE7jn/g5KXn4v72QqpnsPJjWQVVD12 + h6DDUdaQHMsTdYyYIVD 
Jkc8dPDVTLutVnuK2HZ4wQWRoiIWIMsUzePUht0eWi7DJFOlC5NuwS + E6FuxtgFj 
IwJyCr/dLC/u6YtVCAb37UUSu7k3F5iD3hFTt1RyswK7HBDizV1CHIlc2diARfkL
CwRpYc/SlpZNgbAXaUzwHhtIQjCuRXQGsXtvDFke4CvM9nGe6Uk095yVOAKla1Y = 
= mVny 
----- END PGP SIGNATURE -----
'
```

This is how to break down the message into the XML:

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml = message[/(<\? xml .+)----- BEGIN/m, 1]
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml)
doc.at('IP_Address').text # => " 158.01.52.23 "
```

The magic part is:

```
xml = message[/(<\? xml .+)----- BEGIN/m, 1]
```

That grabs everything from `<? xml` to the line before `----- BEGIN`. Then `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse` can create a DOM which is searchable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to simply hunting for IP address, I would forget about nokogiri:

```
puts $~[1] if s =~ /<IP_Address>\s*([\d.]+)\s*<\/\s*IP_Address>/m
```

would do the trick assuming the file content was loaded in `s` with

```
s = File.read(...)
```

Hope it helps.

**UPD** To grep out the XML:

```
xml = $~[1] if s =~ /(<\?\s*xml.*?Infringement>)/m
```

Comment: def ip
    s = Nokogiri::XML("mail/*.txt")
    puts $~[1] if s =~ /<IP_Address>\s*([\d.]+)\s*<\/\s*IP_Address>/m
  end

returns nill

Comment: Please forget about nokogiri. If your file is `a.txt` simply run `puts $~[1] if File.read('a.txt') =~ /<IP_Address>\s*([\d.]+)\s*<\/\s*IP_Address>/m`

Comment: how can I clear all before <?xml and after the closing tag, and parse with nokogiri?

Comment: You totally screwed me up. I shew how to get ip address. I shew how to get the whole xml. What do you want from me now? I never used nokogiri and never will do.